# Does init script support something like systemd user service?

Tags: linux, systemd, sysvinit

In recent Linux distributions, systemd has replaced the traditional /etc/init.d scripts. And it can support user services
`systemctl --user start my.service`

I wonder if we can do similar things with init scripts? i.e. let a service run by a regular user when the system boots up

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Do you mean that you are running some rc-like init system OR ( that you are running a systemd init system and ( would want to start systemd services the rc way ? OR would want to start rc-like services ? ))

Comment: Hey, DrizzleX, I'm sorry, but it's really not clear what you'd like to do. Can you give us a **concrete** example of what you want to do? What you describe *sounds* illogical.

Answer (score 0):

Any initscript can run any command as any user just by using `su $user -c "/home/$user/onboot.sh"`.  And that would just launch a user script on boot, to which they can run whatever they want.   If I wanted to provide a user a facility like systemd user services, I would give them supervisord, and write a initscript to autostart it on boot.  Of course, they could do something similiar themselves just by creating a cronjob that runs ever minute that starts supervisord if it is not running already.  That will work just the same without any initscript.

Comment: I'm not sure I rightly understood the question. Anyway ! Whatever my understanding, you just cannot write *" ... launch a user script on boot, to which they can run **whatever** they want "*. Whatever, whatever… The order in which services are launched should be considered in case the service being launched requires other services being already launched or/and this service is needed by other services that should be launched after.